# How can i scale a texture to the given size in pixel with SharpDX.Direct3D9?

Tags: c#, image, directx, directx-9, sharpdx

I'm currently trying to scale a texture to the given size in pixels via SharpDX.Direct3D9.

I have the following code which draws a texture on the screen (2D)

```
public static bool DrawTexture(IntPtr device, IntPtr txt, RectangleF rect, float rotation, Color tint)
        {
            try {
                Texture texture = (Texture)txt;
                Matrix m = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.Translation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f) * Matrix.Scaling(rect.Width, rect.Height, 1.0f) * Matrix.RotationZ(rotation) * Matrix.Translation(rect.X, rect.Y, 0.0f);
                using (Sprite s = new Sprite((Device)device)) {
                    s.Begin();
                    s.Transform = m;
                    s.Draw(texture, tint.ToRawColorBGRA());
                    s.End();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Main.managerInstance.console.PrintError(string.Format("[Direct3D9] An error occured while trying to draw texture. Details: {0}", ex.ToString()));
            }
            return false;
        }
```

`Matrix.Scaling(rect.Width, rect.Height, 1.0f)` is responsible for scaling my texture to the given size (128x128 pixel).

But as far as i understand, the Matrix.Scaling function takes in a float from 0 - 1 where 1 is the full texture size and 2 would be double the texture size. But i would like to enter the size in pixel and not in units(?).

So i tried the following:

```
Size res = CGame.Resolution;
float cW = rect.Width / res.Width;
float cH = rect.Height / res.Height;
Matrix m = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.Translation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f) * Matrix.Scaling(cW, cH, 1.0f) * Matrix.RotationZ(rotation) * Matrix.Translation(rect.X, rect.Y, 0.0f);
```

I divide the given texture Width and Height (which is 128x128 pixel) by the Width and Height of the current screen resolution (Which in my case is 1920x1080).

This leaves me with the following:

[The result of the division by the screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAtag.png)

As you can see there is a red rectangle in the texture, which is actually 128x128 pixel in size, and in the background, there is my texture, which is supposed to be scaled to 128x128 but as you can see, it clearly is larger then the red rectangle which is 128x128.

Here is how i load my texture

```
// D3DX.DefaultNonPowerOf2 = -2
Texture t = Texture.FromFile(device, filePath, D3DX.DefaultNonPowerOf2, D3DX.DefaultNonPowerOf2, 1, Usage.None, Format.Unknown, Pool.Managed, Filter.None, Filter.None, 0);
```

If someone could help me out with this problem i would be really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

Needed to divide the target Size of the texture by the actual texture size like so:

```
SurfaceDescription sd = texture.GetLevelDescription(0);
float cW = rect.Width / sd.Width;
float cH = rect.Height / sd.Height;
```